# nilpotent linear transformation and its adjoint exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators, nilpotence

The problem statement.

Let $(V,<,>)$ be a finite dimensional vector space equipped with an inner product, whose dimension is $n$, and let $f:V \to V$ be a nilpotent linear transformation such that $f \circ f^*=f^* \circ f$. Prove that $f=0$.

The attempt at a solution:

I know that there is $ k \in \mathbb N, k\leq n$: $f^k=0$.  If I compose $f \circ f^*$ with itself $k-1$ times, then $(f \circ f^*)^k$. As $f \circ f^*=f^* \circ f$, one can easily verify $(f \circ f^*)^k=f^k \circ (f^*)^k=0 \circ (f^*)^k=0$

Then $(f \circ f^*)^k=(f^* \circ f)^k=0$

At this point I got stuck.

I suppose that at some point, if I could show that $f^* \circ f=0$, I must use the property that characterizes $f^*$, which is: $<f(v),w>=<v,f^*(w)>$ and try to conclude that $||f(v)||=0$ for all $v \in V$. I would appreciate suggestions to go in this direction or another idea to get to the solution.

Comment: How do you get $f^*f=0$ ?

Comment: Oh, you're right, I've concluded that $(f^* \circ f)^k=(f \circ f^*)^k=0$, but not $f^* \circ f$

Comment: I have an argument for it on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $f^*f=0$
$$(f(x),f(x))=(f^*f(x),x)=0$$ so $f(x)=0$.

To show $f^*f=0$ let $n$ be minimal such that  $(f^*f)^n=0$
then

$$((f^*f)^{n-1}(x), (f^*f)^{n-1}(x))=
((f^*f)^{2n-2}(x), x)$$ this follows from the fact that $f^{**}=f$ and $f$ commutes with $f^*$. Now if $n\geq 2$ then $2n-2 \geq n$ and $(f^*f)^{2n-2}=0$ so we have 
$((f^*f)^{n-1}(x), (f^*f)^{n-1}(x))=0$ for all $x$ and thus $(f^*f)^{n-1}=0$ contradicting the choice of $n$. So $n \leq 1$.

Comment: Sorry if it is obvious but I could't follow this:$((f^*f)^{n-1}(x), (f^*f)^{n-1}(x))=
((f^*f)^{2n-2}(x), x)=0$, this is true if and only if $2n-2 \geq n$ iff $n \geq 2$

Comment: What dont you follow ?

Comment: and I still don't get why $((f^*f)^{n-1}(x), (f^*f)^{n-1}(x))=
((f^*f)^{2n-2}(x), x)$

Comment: I am using $(f^*f)^*=f^*f$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is normal, we have an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras $\mathbb{C}[f,f^*] \cong C(\sigma(f))$. The algebra on the right is reduced, hence also the algebra on the left.

Answer (score 0):

When $V$ is defined over $\mathbb C$, every normal operator on $V$ is diagonalizable. Being $f$ diagonalizable and having $0$ as the only eigenvalue, the result follows.